Real *-Subalgebras of the Real Analog of $B(H)$ and their Strong Closures
We know for $A$ a $*$-subalgebra of $B(H),$ $A$ is strongly dense in its double commutant $A''.$ Consider the following situation: $H$ is separable, $(e_n)$ an orthonormal basis on it. Let $B(H)_\mathbb{R}$ be the operators whose matrix coefficients w.r.t. to $(e_n)$ are all real, and take this to be a real C$^*$-algebra. Now let $A$ be a real $*$-subalgebra of $B(H)_\mathbb{R}.$ Is $A$ still strongly dense in $A''?$ It seems to me nothing changes in the proof given in Murphy, but I could be sorely mistaken.
Edit: I think it suffices to show that $B(H)_\mathbb{R}$ is in fact a real C$^*$-algebra, and this can be achieved by a $*$-isomorphism from $B(H)_\mathbb{R}$ to $B(\tilde{H})$, where $\tilde{H}$ is the "real Hilbert subspace" of $H,$ i.e. the closed real span of $(e_n).$ Is this line of thinking correct?

You need to show the strong topology on $B(H)_\mathbb{R}$, induced by vectors in $H$; and the strong topology on $B(\tilde{H})$, induced by vectors in $\tilde{H}$, coincide. But other than that, the proof in Murphy goes through as is.

@DavidGao Great! It suffices to prove the latter is stronger than the former, and this can be done with a routine application of Parseval’s. Thank you so much!
